# What kind of content can I put in the figure element?

Tags: html

I realized that I've been using the `<figure>` element wrong after reading the spec.

> The figure element represents a unit of content, optionally with a
>   caption, that is self-contained, that is typically referenced as a
>   single unit from the main flow of the document, and that can be moved
>   away from the main flow of the document without affecting the
>   document’s meaning.

Correct me if I'm wrong. It meant to me that the `<figure>` element can be moved around within the page without causing any trouble to the main content.

Could someone explain what the following portion means ?

> that is typically referenced as a single unit from the main flow of the document

And also some examples where the figure element could be used ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just think of the `<figure>` element as having the exact same purpose as a "figure" would in a book, magazine, academic article, etc. For instance, some authors use a figure to illustrate an idea, usually including a reference to it in the text with something like "**See Figure 1**."

In the quote you referenced in your question, the part "able to move the element around without affecting the document's meaning," means that since you should reference the figure somewhere in your text (by saying something like "See Figure 1"), it doesn't matter where you put the figure in the flow of the document (right side, bottom, left side, center, etc.) The reader is going to come across the **See Figure 1** note in your text and naturally scan the page for something with a caption of **Figure 1: (some caption...)**.

HTML is a semantic language, so instead of using a `<div>` in HTML to achieve this purpose, it's more appropriate to use the `<figure>` tag. As far as the spec goes, it's just giving a description of when and how it is most semantically appropriate to use the `<figure>`; it's doing nothing more than describing how figures are used in the real world, but from an HTML perspective. If you find yourself using a `<figure>` element in your document but none of the text in your document is even related to the contents of the figure (your company logo next to a blog about something not directly describing your company logo), or the placement of your element is entirely dependent on its placement (like an icon inside a button or a user's profile image, etc.), then you shouldn't be using a figure.

Hope that helps.

Also, take a look at the example use of a figure [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_figure):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>
    The Pulpit Rock is a massive cliff 604 metres (1982 feet) above
    Lysefjorden, opposite the Kjerag plateau, in Forsand, Ryfylke, Norway. 
    The top of the cliff is approximately 25 by 25 metres (82 by 82 feet) 
    square and almost flat, and is a famous tourist attraction in Norway. 

    <strong><a href='#figure1'>(See figure 1)</a></strong>
</p>

<figure id="figure1">
    <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228">
    <figcaption>Figure 1 - A view of the pulpit rock in Norway.</figcaption>
</figure>

</body>
</html>
```

Notice how the text in the example 'document' is describing a certain location and the author uses an image as an illustration. In a big document, or if this illustration was further away in the page, the author would probably use the **See Figure...** notation.

There's not really a semantically-sound way to reference the figure from within your text. However, make sure your figure has a `<figcaption>` and put your reference to the figure in `<strong>` or `<em>` tags. You can go a step further and wrap the reference in a hyperlink that links to the figure in the page as such:

```
<strong><a href='#figure1'>Figure 1</a></strong>
```

Comment: So "that is typically referenced as a single unit from the main flow of the document" means that the figure is referenced from within the text, correct ?

Comment: +1 for good explanation. Is there some way to reference the figure from text symantic? I mean, for `label` we have the attribute `for`. Is there something euqivalent for `figure`?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Thanks. I've updated my answer in response to your question with an example. In short, there is no 'right' way, I think it's up to you to **figure** (pun intended) out how to best indicate it to the viewer - the HTML semantic nazis won't hunt you down ;].