# Can I use a DIV inside a FIGURE tag on HTML?

Tags: html, css

For the styling I need to add to a page, I have to wrap the img tag with another tag so it doesn't affect the figcaption tag. The only way I found I can do this is by wrapping the img tag with a Div tag inside of figure tag, can I do this? is this a valid HTML and CSS design?

This is how the HTML looks like:

```
<figure>
  <div>
    <img />
  </div>

<figcaption> <figcaption>

</ figure>
```

Comment: You wont need, you can better to use symantic html, good for accessbility and reading purpose

Comment: Similar, but not the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30292505/what-kind-of-content-can-i-put-in-the-figure-element

Comment: I suspect this is not the real question you should be asking. WHY do you need the div? What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @paulie-d the image covers the page left and right with a gradient overlay, and there's a cut-off height with overflow hidden and I'm trying to show the figcaption outside the overflow hidden. So the div is to add an :after to the img tag to show the gradient overlay, but without affecting the figcaption. I hope you get the point.

Answer (score 2):

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure), `figure` can have permitted content from the [flow-content category](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content), to which `div` belongs.

So technically yes, you are allowed to put a `div` in a `figure`, but make sure you understand the semantics of the `figure` element, and that your usage of the figure element stays in line with those semantics.

Comment: How do I know if it follows the semantics? I have a hero image on the page that needs styling, can't find another way to do this without adding a DIV, and I don't want to get in the way of the figcaption. Thanks,

Comment: Read about the semantics and compare that with the intention you're using it in.